# How to target a subdomain to another website directory like aliases

Tags: php, cpanel, cname

how to target a subdomain to another website directory like aliases

**Ex:**

```
 1. serv1.domain1.com/index.php -> domain2.com/serv1/index.php
 2. serv1.domain1.com/main.php -> domain2.com/serv1/main.php
```

why this? my PHP code wants privacy

Answer (score 0):

Either [proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) the request:

```
ProxyPass "/index.php" "http://domain2.com/serv1/index.php"
```

… or [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) to it:

```
Redirect temp "/index.php" "http://domain2.com/serv1/index.php"
```

… or just set up [the root directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) to point there:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/serv1/
```